# wp_get_menu_array(), Add active classes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wp_get_menu_array() to use my own markup.  What I haven't figured out is how to include the following current menu item classes:

1. current-menu-item
2. current-menu-ancestor
3. current-menu-parent
4. current_page_parent
5. current_page_ancestor

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I'm not sure.  Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php $mainMenu = wp_get_menu_array('Menu 1');?>

<ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" role="list">
    <?php foreach ($mainMenu as $parentItem) :
            $childrenCount = count($parentItem['children']);
            $childCountTotal = $childrenCount > 0;
            $hasChildren = $childCountTotal ? 'navbar-nav__list-item navbar-nav__has-children' : 'navbar-nav__list-item';
            $parentUrl = $childCountTotal ? '#' : $parentItem['url'];
            $dropDownAttrs = $childCountTotal ? 'data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="button"':'';
            $dropDownClass = $childCountTotal ? 'navbar-nav__dropdown-toggle navbar-nav__link': 'navbar-nav__link';
            // print_r($parentItem);
        ?>
        <li id="list-<?= $parentItem['ID']?>" class="<?= $hasChildren;?>" role="listitem">
            <a id="menu-item-id-<?= $parentItem['ID']?>" href="<?= $parentUrl;?>" class="<?= $dropDownClass;?>" <?= $dropDownAttrs;?> data-js="dropdown-button">
                <?= $parentItem['title'];?>
            </a>
            <?php if($childCountTotal):?>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav__dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-id-<?= $parentItem['ID']?>" role="list">
                    <div class="container navbar-nav__mega-container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php foreach ($parentItem['children'] as $childItem) :
                                $childrenCount = count($childItem['children']);
                                $childCountTotal = $childrenCount > 0;
                                $hasGrandChildren = $childCountTotal ? 'col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-auto me-4 ':'';
                            ?>
                                <li class="<?= $hasGrandChildren;?> <?= $childItem['classes'];?>" role="listitem">
                                    <?php if($childCountTotal):?>
                                        <span class="navbar-nav__grand-parent">
                                            <?= $childItem['title'];?>
                                        </span>
                                        <ul class="navbar-nav__grandchild-list" role="list">
                                            <?php foreach ($childItem['children'] as $grandChild) : ?>
                                                <li id="menu-item-<?= $grandChild['ID'];?>" class="navbar-nav__grandchild-list-item <?= $grandChild['classes']?>" role="listitem">
                                                    <a href="<?= $grandChild['url'];?>" class="navbar-nav__grandchild-link <?= $grandChild['active-class'];?>">
                                                        <?= $grandChild['title'];?>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php else:?>
                                        <a href="<?= $childItem['url'];?>" class="">
                                            <?= $childItem['title'];?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            <?php endif;?>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is `wp_get_menu_array` supposed to be a native WP function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_active_menu( $mainMenu ) {
$actual_link = ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? "https" : "http" ) . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if ( $actual_link == $parentItem->url ) {
    return 'active';
}
return '';
}
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't quite do it.

As I would need to know if a parent or grand parent is active ( for example the dropdowns, dropdowns wouldn't have the URL present, just a hash )

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it